# How to call form-method from usercontrol?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

.NET noob here:

Why can't I reach the method in the form containing the panel (containing then uc)

```
// Works and displays "form1"
MessageBox.Show(this.Parent.Parent.Name);
// Produce an error at build
this.Parent.Parent.MethodTest("test");
```

This is the `MethodTest` in `:`

```
public void MethodTest(string newValue)
{ 
    this.textBox1.Text = newValue; 
}
```

regards,
/t

Comment: A cast is required since Parent is of type Control, not Form1.  Do not do this, raise an event instead.

Comment: Ok. I dig into events and delegates. Building real-time systems, I have this habit of putting state machine code in their respective presentation objects. May sound ugly but logic gets encapsulated and easy to follow. Thankful for further recommendations.

Comment: It isn't encapsulated, that's the problem.  Rename the form class or drop the control on another form and the code fails miserably.  An event isolates it.

Answer (score 2):

Because the compiler doesn't know what type this.Parent.Parent is.

Use `((form1)this.Parent.Parent).MethodTest("test");`

Its not encouraged to do it this way though. Better use another way!

Comment: Not to mention, you don't always know what type the form is so it might not always be Form1 which would make the cast fail.

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast the parent to the form type

```
((Form1)this.Parent.Parent).MethodTest("Test");
```

This can get tricky though if you're using nested forms/controls, plus you don't really know which form is hosting it so the cast could fail. I would suggest passing a delegate. (this is pseudo code btw)

```
    public delegate MyDelegate(string newValue);

   //form
    form_load()
    {
      myControl.MethodDelegate = new MyDelegate(MethodTest);
    }

    //Control

    someEvent()
    {
       this.MethodDelegate("Test");
    }
```

Note: I just saw Hans comment, but I would recommend not doing an event unless you can properly unregister the handlers to prevent memory leaks which I have not seen many devs do correctly, but if you can then an even might be better than a delegate.